# $injector:unpr when trying to add service

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am trying to use service.js to post http over JSON :-

```
App.service('loginService', function($http, $scope) {
var user = {};
this.login = function(user) {
   var request = {
      "user": user.id,
      "password": user.pass
    };
    var promise = $http.post("http://vlinux:9099/Authenticate", request);
    return promise.data;
  }
});
```

But I get following error

> angular.min.js:125 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20loginService

Comment: post how you are using this in controller

Comment: You can't use `$scope` on a service, removing it will solve your issue